# Tooltip bug, hides element, Joomla and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

I am experiencing an annoying bug with a JOOMLA template that also uses bootstrap.

Example:

If you go here: [LINK](http://sscotti.net/component/osproperty/beautiful-pool-view-condo-005)

at the bottom of the page there is a form.  If you put the mouse in or over (hover or otherwise activate the tooltip) in one of the date input fields and then the tooltip displays and when you leave with the mouse the entire field is set to display:none.  Not sure if this is a bootstrap bug, conflict with other .js libraries, etc.  Wondering if you can suggest a fix and a way to go about solving.  Ideally, I would like to not allow the user to manually enter a date into the field and just have them use the built in Joomla datapicker.

As for debugging, I am just starting to get back into this and could use suggestions for debugging.  Is there a way to use a debugger like web developer toolbar or firebug to capture the event that is getting fired when the mouse leaves the field and the track functions that execute afterwards.  Could maybe find the exact problem that way.

Joomla is OK, but that is the problem with bloated CMS systems.  So much code, potential for conflicts and upgrade issues with overwriting of edits.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the behavior is browser dependent.  As a temp fix I had added display:inline-block !important to the element and this fixes it in Safari, but FireFox seems to still have the bug, at least on a Mac.

Comment: Hi, I see no problem in Firefox, seems like the fix is OK, but I don't see any tooltip. Anyway I had similar problem and the conflict was between JQuery - Chosen - Mootools. Disabling Mootools helped me

Comment: Might be a Mootools conflict.  I am using a Joomla! template that uses that and a bunch of other .css and .js, maybe too many.  I think that it is a little buggy.  It isn't an issue since I am not using the built in form and am using a different one, so problem solved, but thanks.